# next-auth session update method not working

Tags: session, next.js, jwt, next-auth

I have an auth system that I created with next-auth. I update the data again with a form in the application. And then I call the update method on the next auth side. But no matter what I do, unless I log out and log in again, old outdated data returns to the session side.

My custom useAuth hook;

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { getSession, useSession } from 'next-auth/react';

const useAuth = () => {
  const { data, update } = useSession();

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      // getSession fonksiyonu ile mevcut oturumu al
      const userSession = await getSession();

      if (userSession) {
        // Some redux operations can be done
      }
    };

    fetchData();
  }, [data, update]);

  return { ...data, update };
};

export default useAuth;
```

How I use it;

```
const { user, update } = useAuth();
const activeUser: User = user;

const submitHandler: SubmitHandler<CompleteOrganisationFormValues> = async (formData:CompleteOrganisationFormValues) => {
    setLoading(true);

    try {
      const { message } = await OrganisationService.completeOrgInfo(formData, activeUser?.id);

      setLoading(false);
      if (message === "OK") {
        await update()
        toast.success(`Succesfuly!`);
        setCompleteOrgInfoStatus(true);
      }
    } catch (error: any | { type: string; message: string; }) {
      setLoading(false);
      console.error(error)
      if(error?.message) {
        toast.error(`${error?.message}`);
      }
    }
  }
```

My [...nextauth].ts file callbacks;

```
callbacks: {
    async session({ session, token } : any) {
      session.accessToken = token.accessToken;
      session.user = token.user;
      return session;
    },
    async jwt({ token, user }) {
      if (user) {
        token.accessToken = user.id;
        token.user = user;
      }
      return token;
    },
  }
```

I tried to use the update method but I couldn't see the data I updated in the db in the session.